# Applescript folder action to make folders in new folder?

Tags: applescript, directory

I know this should be easy, but I'm just not finding it. We have a program that creates a new folder automatically in Users/Shared/. The folder is a different name every time. So that's the variable.

I need a folder action that will do the following:

When new folder is copied or created in Users/Shared/,

Create (or copy from another location) two new folders inside that new folder, one named "To" and one named "From".

I tried "recording" one, but it did nothing.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
on adding folder items to theFolder after receiving droppedItems
    repeat with anItem in droppedItems
        tell application "System Events" to get kind of (contents of anItem) = "Folder"
        if the result then do shell script "mkdir -p " & (quoted form of (POSIX path of anItem)) & "{\"To\",\"From\"}"
    end repeat
end adding folder items to
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks! That did it. Been banging my head againts the wall too long on this one!

Comment: Hi there,
This was working great when I set it up. It still creates the folders when I drag a new one in, or do cmd-shift-N, but when the user creates a new folder through the web interface, the To/From folders are not created anymore.

Any idea why this would stop working?

Thanks a lot,